# Setting ComboBox enabled using double mouse click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my project I have multi-column ListView that contains a ObservableCollection of People objects. Their names, schooling areas and other various data form each of the GridViewColumns. Some of the GridViewColumns contain a TextBox and others contain a ComboBox. I am trying to set the IsEnable property on the locationCmboBx based on a MouseDoubleClick event from one of the other GridViewColumns. Below I have snippet of my XAML code for the area in question.

```
<ListView x:Name="PeopleListView" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0" Height="315" Width="560" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="80">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Name="personNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="Control_MouseDoubleClick" Width="80" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

      <! -- More GridViewColumns Here -->

            <GridViewColumn Header="School" Width="70">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="locationCmboBx" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SchoolLocations, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="OnCmboBxLoad" Width="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <ComboBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.IsEditable, ElementName=GuardbandListView}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ComboBox.Style>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn> 

        <! -- More GridViewColumns Here -->   

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Here I have my IsEditable property that I created for each People object in the ObservableCollection being used to populate the PeopleListView. This property is set when the user double clicks on one of the cells in a row on the ListView. When IsEditable is set to true the IsEnabled property for the locationCmboBx should be set to true as well allowing the user to change the selected value along with the other data in the row.

```
public bool IsEditable
{
    get { return _IsEditable; }

    set
    {
        if (_IsEditable != value)
        {
            _IsEditable = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsEditable");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I only want the selected row in the PeopleListView to be affected by this event but what is happening is that if I have multiple rows then each ComboBox in each row gets it's IsEnabled property set too. Anyway around this?

Comment: I don't understand what is `GuardbandListView`?!

Comment: That is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Use following to trigger double click event, Command Parameters only if you want to pass any else remove it.

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the EventName property here is only that, a name. The Command property is what I use to trigger my MouseDoubleClick event and in my case I might need to use the CommandParameter property. Is that all correct?

Comment: `EventName="MouseDoubleClick"` will be double click only if you want action to be performed on double click , For single click `EventName="Click"`

Yes Command property is what you use to trigger my MouseDoubleClick event.

and you can you command parameters if you want to send any parameters when you click on comboBox. like if you want to send 1 then keep `CommandParameter ="1"`